# Unable to print statement in TestNg after a method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Please advise, the print statement is not working, after a method (login) in TestNG.
It perfectly prints the login-method statement.

```
   package lectures;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class DependencyAnnot extends TestBase {
        // the code is written to check the inheritancce which helps us from hardcoding
        // the values
        public void OpenBrowser() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            System.out.println("executing the browser opening");
        login();

    }

}
```

the login method was inherited from class"TestBase"
the code is as follows

```
public class TestBase {

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\bharath\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    public WebDriver driver = null;


    @Test
    public void login() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        // properies class is used to scan and fileinput stream gives us location to scan

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\raj\\src\\lectures\\datadriven.properties");
        prop.load(fis);

        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("username"));
        System.out.println("opening browser");
        // instead of hard-coding the browser we are using datadriver folder to help us
        // choose the correct browser
        if (prop.getProperty("browser").contains("chrome"))// if the datadriven.properties file has browser = chrome use
                                                            // it else its firefox
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            // a webdriver defined in if statemetn is only valid in that if statemeent so
            // its better to define after class

        } else {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        System.out.println("closing browser");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your parent login() method is now a kind of tooling you would like to reuse multiple times in your different tests.

So this is no more a test itself.

Move the @Test annotation into the child class on 'OpenBrowser' method. And remove it from login()

Test frameworks will only execute method with'@Test' annotation.